# Best way to compare (approximately) two real numbers

Tags: python, compare, numerical

I am new with Python but I need to code in it for my thesis. So basically I've created a new set of numbers and I want to prove that it is computable (at least subset of it). However, now I am still building some definitions on real numbers as my new set is based on it. My question is, how can I compare (which one is the greater one) two real numbers in Python? I know that generally comparing two real numbers are not computable. But I am sure there is a way to do kind of approximation, right? Any ideas? Cheers!

Comment: you could use math.isclose(). see the discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python

Comment: @Jacobr365: I guess that's just for equality comparison right?

Comment: Comparing two `float`s is trivial; it's mapping real numbers to `float`s in such a way that preserves ordering that causes problems.